# Mui Datagrid not populating, data is there

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, redux-toolkit

I have a few Mui datagrids through my app. I recently switched over to using RTK Query for the api and was able to get all the grids functioning and displaying fine. I honestly do not know what changed (since it took place after I was done mucking with the grid components and was adjusting the auth/login to RTK) but 3 of the 4 are displaying an empty grid with no errors. I can console the data, and even the corner of the grids shows the total number of entries, which reflects the changes if I add an item to the array that should be displayed by the grid. I already had the container components set to display: flex and set autoHeight and autoWidth on the grids. I've tried adjusting the containers, even putting height to 5000, with no change. As I mentioned, I have 1 that still displays correctly, and even copying the display props for that grid to the others had no effect.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { DataGrid, GridActionsCellItem } from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useGetVisitsByUserIdQuery } from '../../redux/apiSlice';
import { CircularProgress, Box } from '@mui/material';

const UserVisits = ({ user }) => {


const userId = user._id

const {
  data,
  isLoading,
  isSuccess
} = useGetVisitsByUserIdQuery(userId);

console.log(data)

const columns = 

   [
  {
    field: 'client', 
    headerName: 'Client', 
    width: 150,
    renderCell: (params) => {
     return (
     <Link to={`/ClientChart/${params?.value?._id}`}>{params?.value?.fullName}</Link>
     )}
  },
  {
    field: 'visitStart',
    headerName: 'Start Time',
    type: 'date',
    width: 200,
    valueFormatter: (params) => {
      const date = new Date(params.value);
      let options = {
        year: "numeric",
        month: "numeric",
        day: "numeric"
      };
      return date.toLocaleTimeString("en-US", options);
    }
    
  },
  {
    field: 'visitEnd',
    headerName: 'End Time',
    type: 'date',
    width: 200,
    valueFormatter: (params) => {
      const date = new Date(params.value);
      let options = {
        year: "numeric",
        month: "numeric",
        day: "numeric"
      };
      return date.toLocaleTimeString("en-US", options);
    }
    
  },
  {field: 'location', headerName: 'Location', width: 150},
  
   ];

   let content

if (isLoading) {
  content = <CircularProgress />
} else if (isSuccess) {
  content = 
  <div style={{ display: 'flex', height: '100%'}}>
    <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
  { data &&
    <DataGrid 
      autoHeight
      autoWidth
      getRowId={(row) => row.id}
      rows={data}
      columns={columns}
      rowsPerPageOptions={[20, 50, 100]}
      autoPageSize
      //sx={{ height: '100%', width: '100%' }}
  
 />}
 </Box>
  </div>

}



  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Visits</h1>
    
      <div>
       {content}
      </div>
      
      
    </div>
  )
}
```

[image: grid]

If I push new data to the grid, the number of entries in the bottom right corner adjusts, and the console shows the correct array of data, as well as Redux DevTools showing the data in state. Even manually adjusting the height of the div/Box containing the grid, the grid itself never changes in height.

Again they had been working perfectly, and I'm at a total loss as to what would have affected them. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was resolved by removing 'autoPageSize' from the Datagrid props. Playing with it, it seems that autoHeight and autoPageSize cause the grid to break when in place together.

Could not find any specific references online to this being an issue, but I was able to recreate the issue on this codesandbox I found: https://codesandbox.io/s/datagrid-v5-0-1-autoheight-autopagesize-9dy64?file=/src/App.tsx

If you add in autoPageSize to the datagrid props, the grid goes empty.